PageSpeed insights improve
i have project on next.js, main point is page speed insights improvement. on desktop i reached perfect scores here is desktop insights

but mobile same page insights is not fixed its like 84, 96, 78

sometimes mobile speed is 96 so i dont know what to do have tried many ways like images optimization and dynamic imports but still on mmobile it has bad insights.
here is website url
website
